# Best way to ensure smooth page transitions in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, animation, navigation, maui

Using Shell navigation in dotNET MAUI, what is the best (most reliable) way to ensure that page transitions are always animating and doing this as smooth as possible, across different devices?

I did find the simplest solution but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. The way I'm currently doing it does not seem all too reliable, especially across different (slower and faster) devices. Is this really the best / most acceptable way?

**Update for accepted answer**:
The accepted answer has made a huge difference for me! Many lists of objects could be loaded into the GlobalViewModel, throughout my entire application. I never knew I was making so many copies. This has sped up my entire application on every page!

**The actual problem:**
I noticed one of my pages having slightly more data to load. Although in my opinion still a pretty acceptable amount, the page transition doesn't show because loading data causes a lag.

**My current solution:**
I'm navigating to a page using Shell `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(PageName)}", true, Params);` and this is a very primitive/simple example of a destination page that I would have:

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Models"
             xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:PageNameViewModel">
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <tk:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding OnAppearingCommand}" EventName="Appearing"/>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:Item">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <!-- Using item data here -->
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel:

I am basically delaying all the stuff in `OnAppearing()` to animate first, before actually populating the page:

```
public class PageNameViewModel : BaseViewModel, IQueryAttributable
{
    private List<Item> items { get; set; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new();

    public Command OnAppearingCommand { get; private set; }

    public PageNameViewModel()
    {
        OnAppearingCommand = new Command(OnAppearing);
    }

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> Params)
    {
        items = Params["Items"] as items;
    }

    private async void OnAppearing()
    {
        // Delay here to wait for page animation, before populating the page:

        await Task.Delay(500);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

*Please note that, in my case, I have to load the data inside the `Appearing` event in my ViewModel because of the `IQueryAttributable` interface. Properties are set from query parameters after the constructor but before the appearing event in which I populate the view. I am using MAUI Community Toolkit to convert the page appearing event into a command.*

I think this may not be very reliable because on older and slower devices, the delay time might be way too short. On high end devices the delay time might even become obvious and annoying.

Is this an acceptable way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the items are known before you move to the page. Why does the page need to have a copy of the items? Instead, let's refer to the original instance.

Let's assume we have a `GlobalViewModel` singleton, and, in it, let's place the `ObservableCollection`. The intention is that the `ObservableCollection` is available for your entire application.

```cs
public GlobalViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new();
}
```

Note that for collections that you initialize either inline (as depicted above) or in the constructor, you only need to have `get;`.

Register this as a singleton in your `MauiProgram.cs` for dependency injection:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GlobalViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<PageNameViewModel>();
```

Then for your `PageNameViewModel` you can pass in the `GlobalViewModel` singleton via constructor injection parameters:

```cs
public PageViewModel
{
    public GlobalViewModel Global { get; }

    public PageViewModel(GlobalViewModel Global)
    {
        this.Global = Global;
    }
}
```

As mentioned previously, since the property is defined during the constructor, we only need to use `get;` permissions for the property.

In your XAML we can access the collection via `Global.Items`:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Global.Items}">
```

Comment: That was very helpful! Now in my GlobalViewModel, I should not load too much data on first instantiation, otherwise the moment of first instantiation slows down the app, is that right?

Comment: Theoretically, the data is still the same as before. We're just reducing the need to make copies of it. In fact, that data now completely disappears from the parameters, which should reduce a lot of burden. Another benefit of the solution, now that all pages see the same instance, they can also modify the same instance of data.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've already implemented the GlobalViewModel and it works like a charm!

Comment: This is great advice. I do find that the MAUI method of transitioning views is inherently different from the native iOS way (having developed the exact same app in SwiftUI). The child elements do not act the same.